# C# File.Move creates an empty file and IO exception

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

My code processes a video file (using ffmpeg) and creates different qualities (360p, 480p, etc) and formats (mp4 and HLS) of that. After creating these files, I move all of them to another drive (a network location).

my code looks Like this:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(srcFolder);
string filename, destFile = string.Empty, srcFile = string.Empty;
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        srcFile = files[i];
        filename = Path.GetFileName(srcFile);
        destFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, filename);
        File.Move(srcFile, destFile);
    }
}
catch
{
    _logger.LogError("Error in moving file. srcFile: {0}, destFile: {1}", destFile, srcFile);
    throw;
}
```

This process works fine most of the time, but for some files, I get an IO exception every time I run this process.

> System.IO.IOException: The file exists. at System.IO.FileSystem.MoveFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite)

I made sure that **destFolder** does not exist before, nor did the **destFile**.

After logging the error and finding the path of source and target files, I downloaded both of them. The source file is a **.ts** file with a size of 1,048 KB, and the target file is an empty file with the same name (0KB).

This error happened multiple times with the same video, so I assume that it has something to do with the file itself. But I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Do you have access to debug this part?

Comment: Did you try File.Move(srcFile, destFile, true); ? This attempts to override the file if already existing

Comment: I would suggest to do a explicit copy/delete instead of a file.Move when copying to/from network location.

Comment: @SᴇM I'm not able to debug it on the server. I downloaded the original file and ran the program on my computer, everything was fine.

Comment: @NoConnection This probably clears the error, but I need to know why it happens. There may be a problem that causes other failures in the future.

Comment: @Poiter Is there any difference? As far as I know, Move is like Copy+Delete in a transaction.

Comment: Many years ago I had problems with the File.Move command from one network location to an other, even loosing files. So from that time on I only used my own implementation, doing a seperate Copy and Delete, with checks in between, and never had the problem again...

Comment: Hi @Maddie I'm facing the same issue have you find any solution for this

Comment: @ShivamMishra I used the copy+delete approach that Poiter suggested.